# Continue un-escaping when encountering unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, regex

I have a system that processes some provided data.

Before storing the data, I am unescaping the characters like so:

```
Regex.Unescape(text);
```

I ran into a bunch of `ArgumentException: <str> includes an unrecognized escape sequence` because some of the data contained text like:
`\m/` or `\o/` or even `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.

Is there any way that I can ignore the unrecognized sequences and continue to escape the rest of the input?

Comment: Or you first make sure you escape the escape character; replace every single "\" with a "\\".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on `Regex.Unescape` when your string comes from unknown source. See the [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.90).aspx):

> `Unescape` cannot reverse an escaped string perfectly because it cannot deduce precisely which characters were escaped.

Since

> It reverses the transformation performed by the Escape method by removing the escape character (`"\"`) from each character escaped by the method. These include the `\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`,`)`, `^`, `$`,`.`, `#`, and white space characters. In addition, the Unescape method unescapes the closing bracket (`]`) and closing brace (`}`) characters.

and

> It replaces the representation of unprintable characters with the characters themselves. For example, it replaces `\a` with `\x07`. The character representations it replaces are `\a`, `\b`, `\e`, `\n`, `\r`, `\f`, `\t`, and `\v`.

You can emulate `Regex.Unescape` like

```
var unescaped = Regex.Replace(input, @"\\([\\*+?|{}[\]()^$. #])", "$1");
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5C(%5B%5C%5C*%2B%3F%7C%7B%7D%5B%5C%5D()%5E%24.%20%23%5D)&i=%5C(%2C%5C)%2C%5C%5B%2C%5C%5D%2C%5C%7B%2C%5C%7D%2C%5C%7C%2C%5C%5E%2C%5C%24%2C%5C*%2C%5C%2B%2C%5C%3F%2C%5C%5C%2C%20%5C%20%20and%20%5C%23&r=%241)

If there is an escaped character from the `\`, `*`, `+`, `?`, `|`, `{`, `[`, `(`,`)`, `^`, `$`,`.`, `#`, `}` and `]` set, the backslash will get removed.

Comment: Was mainly using `Regex.Unescape` to un-escape unicode characters (e.g. `\u0113`). Using a `Regex.Replace` now: `Regex.Replace(text, @"\\[Uu]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})", m => char.ToString( (char) ushort.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)));`